# Google sheets API v4, copy and paste format from one spreadsheet to another

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

The example here: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/data only allows you to copy and paste format operations for the SAME spreadsheet.

I'm trying to copy paste formats across multiple spreadsheets. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a work around. Here it is:

Let's say I want to copy the format of a range in "test" sheet from spreadsheet A to spreadsheet B with the same sheet name.

1. copy the sheet "test" from spreadsheet A to B with `service.spreadsheets().sheets().copyTo(spreadsheetId=source,sheetId=id, body=data).execute()`
2. Now that the sheets are in the same spreadsheet, use  https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/data to copy format.
3. delete the sheet "Copy of test" with `spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=key, body=data).execute()`

Answer (score 2):

I manged to work around this by using the [spreadsheet.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get) to get all cells with formating. Then I went through each cell building a object body to use on the `batchUbdate` feature.

The code below is an example using python lib:

```
from httplib2 import Http
from apiclient.discovery import build


# Credentials object is obtained through the google oauth flow lib.
def transfer_first_tab_format(credentials, sourcce_spreadsheet_id, dest_spreadsheet_id):

    http_auth = credentials.authorize(Http())
    sheets_service = build(
        'sheets',
        version='v4',
        http=http_auth
    )

    # --------- get source spreadsheet ----------- #
    source_spreadsheet_info = sheets_service.spreadsheets().get(
        spreadsheetId=sourcce_spreadsheet_id, ranges=[]
    ).execute()
    source_sheets = source_spreadsheet_info.get("sheets")

    source_tab = source_sheets[0]
    source_tab_title = source_tab.get("properties", {}).get("title")
    #   ----------------------------   #

    # --------- get destination spreadsheet ----------- #
    dest_spreadsheet_info = sheets_service.spreadsheets().get(
        spreadsheetId=dest_spreadsheet_id, ranges=[]
    ).execute()

    dest_sheets = dest_spreadsheet_info.get("sheets")
    dest_tab = dest_sheets[0]
    dest_tab_id = dest_tab.get("properties", {}).get("sheetId")
    #   ----------------------------   #


    end_col = end_row = source_tab.get("properties", {}).get("gridProperties", {}).get("columnCount")
    
    # you could find a function that converts a number to alphabet letter, 
    # so you could get the letter from position end_col
    letter_col = 'L' # the last column letter or num_to_letter(end_col)
    start_row = 1
    end_row = source_tab.get("properties", {}).get("gridProperties", {}).get("rowCount")

    source_format = sheets_service.spreadsheets().get(
        spreadsheetId=sourcce_spreadsheet_id,
        ranges="{0}!A{1}:{2}{3}".format(source_tab_title, start_row, letter_col, end_row),
        includeGridData=True
    ).execute()

    source_rows = source_format.get("sheets", [{}])[0].get("data", {})[0].get("rowData")
    format_rules = []

    # --- BUILDS THE FORMAT RULES FOR BATCHUPDATE --- #
    for row_index, source_row in enumerate(source_rows):
        source_cells = source_row.get("values")
        for col_index, source_cell in enumerate(source_cells):
            source_cell_format = source_cell.get("effectiveFormat")
            format_rule = {
                "repeatCell": {
                    "range": {
                        "sheetId": dest_tab_id,
                        "startRowIndex": row_index,  # it's 0 indexed. should start at 0
                        "endRowIndex": row_index + 1,
                        "startColumnIndex": col_index,
                        "endColumnIndex": col_index + 1,
                    },
                    "fields": "userEnteredFormat(backgroundColor, horizontalAlignment, textFormat, borders, "
                                "hyperlinkDisplayType, padding, verticalAlignment, wrapStrategy)",
                    "cell": {
                        "userEnteredFormat": source_cell_format
                    }
                }
            }
            # builds the rules for batchupdate
            format_rules.append(format_rule)

    # ---- PERFORM THE BATCH UPDATE ---- #
    body = {
        'requests': [format_rules]
    }
    sheets_service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(
        spreadsheetId=dest_spreadsheet_id,
        body=body
    ).execute()
```

Answer (score 1):

This feature is not supported yet. Even the [Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) from Spreadsheet Apps Script doesn't offer such feature. Try to file a [request here](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Feature%20request&labels=Type-Enhancement,API-Sheets).

Comment: Here it is. https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5225

Comment: I guess it's possible to copy the sheet from A to B, then use the code above to copy the format once in the same sheet. After completion delete the original copied sheet. A round about way to do it.